# DataFrame does not exist whern using read_excel method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Trying to iterate of a dataframe using iterrows, but its telling me it is not defined.

after opening the excel file with read_excel and getting the data into what I believe to be a dataframe it will not let me use iterrows() on the dataframe

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx') 

objDF =  pd.DataFrame(df['RDX']) $Throws does not exist


for (i, r) in objDF.iterrows():
   #do stuff
```

Expected to be able to iterate over the rows and perform a calculation

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback

Comment: Perhaps the column you are looking for is not in the first sheet of the file? Or the header is not correctly identified?

Answer (score -1):

Why are you trying to create a dataframe from a dataframe? Is the sole intention to just iterate across one column of the original dataframe?  If so, you could access the column as follows:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx') 

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['RDX'])
```

Comment: Thanks! Its throwing iterrows() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: Ok so now it's thowing 'df' not defined, this is needlessly complex.